# Removing 'node' sub-domain from middle of consul DNS lookup

Tags: dns, consul

I have a reasonably ephemeral environment, with machines running consul agent on startup and registering themselves as nodes.

As there are enough Consul servers I would like to use Consul DNS internally to locate machines.

The issue is that the machines are named `somevm.example.com` rather than `somevm.node.consul`

I can change the domain in the consul config file, but that still leaves the 'node' sub-domain in the middle of the lookup: `somevm.node.example.com`, which is not correct.

Can I coax consul into changing this? Or can I dynamically change this, (direct sub, dynamic CNAME etc), in some DNS server/Proxy that I am inevitably going to have to run to resolve on port 53 rather than 8600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just investigating this a while back, currently it isn't possible to remove the `node` part using only Consul, however you can run [coredns](https://coredns.io/) on port 53, proxying and rewriting requests to and from Consul by leveraging the [rewrite](https://coredns.io/plugins/rewrite/) plugin.

The rewrite plugin documentation includes detailed examples on rewriting parts of the dns query and response and includes examples specific to Consul.

Hope it helps.